# Different behavior in VS 2008 and VS 2017 for static arrary

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I have written exact same lines of code in Visual 2008 and 2017. I am getting different output.

```
int main()
{

 static int  arr[] = {1,2};

 int * ptr = arr;
 int val = ptr[2];

 cout<<val;
 return 0;
}
```

Output in Visual Studio 2017,

> 39029

Output in Visual Studio 2008,

> 0

Also, in debug, I get 0 in both the Visual Studios.

Why both the versions of Visual Studio behaving differently for the Release build?

Does making array non-static makes difference in behavior?

Comment: Undefined behaviour

Comment: The behaviour is undefined, since it accesses the third element of an array with two elements.    Results changing with compiler version, or between compilers, or with different optimisation settings, are among the many (theoretically infinite) possible consequences.     Making the array non-static does not eliminate the undefined behaviour.    In short - if you want to access `ptr[2]` without undefined behavior, ensure `arr` has three elements or more.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interesting behavior with dynamically allocated array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969609/interesting-behavior-with-dynamically-allocated-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Unefined behaviour is undefined.* You're accessing the array out of bounds (only `[0]` and `[1]` would be valid indices), which means literally anything can happen.

Comment: I got your point. I have edited my question a little. Does making array non-static makes any difference?

Comment: @PranitKothari No difference: **undefined behaviour is undefined.** If you access an array out of bounds, you have UB, period.

Answer (score 0):

`ptr[2]` is not available and different compilers may show different incorrect answers.

Some compilers will show `0` and some others may show big numbers.